# Laravel & HTMLPurifier Autoloading Problems

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble setting up HTMLPurifier to work in Laravel. The following is my code

```
require_once 'C:\wamp\www\workbench\vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.autoload.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', 'strong,em,a[href],ul,ol,li,p,blockquote,h1,h2');
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', '');
$config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', true);
$config->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', false);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

But when I run my application I receive the following:

> Class 'Workbench\Dailies\Repositories\Stories\HTMLPurifier_Config' not found

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: It looks like you are in a namespace, try using `\HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault()`. Also, try normalizing your `require_once()`'s slashes (some are `\`, some are `/`).

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. use [**mews purifier**](https://packagist.org/packages/mews/purifier)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install htmlpurifier is to use [mewebstudio's purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier)

For further references, try not to use absolute path in your require_once statements. 
When you will install it with composer ( mewebstudios purifier ), you won't need to reference the autoloader because composer will do it for you

To install, simply add it to your composer.json file :

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "mews/purifier": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

To answer your question directly, HTMLPurifier_Config class is not found because it's trying to find it in your current namspace ( i.e. 'Workbench\Dailies\Repositories\Stories\HTMLPurifier_Config  ) and not in it's namespace